# Use Jconsole for a Docker container inside or outside a GCP VM

Tags: docker, jmx, jconsole

Well, I have a vm in gcp and inside I run a Kafka docker Container. So I want to monitor Kafka with Jconsole (JMX). Can I do that with a way inside the VM or not?
Also, what steps should I follow for having access in my VM container from outside ?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm#enabling_the_jvm_monitoring_plugin)? If so Kafka plugin is deprecated.

Comment: Not exactly but thanks!!!